# How to change dimension of input during TensorFlow import_graph_def

Tags: python, tensorflow

My scenario:

1. Define an RNN model structure and train it using an input with fixed batch size and sequence length.
2. Freeze the model (i.e. converting all trainable variables into constants) producing a `GraphDef` containing everything one needs to use the model at test-time (via `tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants`).
3. Import the `GraphDef` via `tf.import_graph_def` and replace the input using the `input_map` argument. The new input needs to have arbitrary batch size and sequence length.

The problem: All of the above works until I pass in an input to the test-time graph that uses a batch size or sequence length that differs from the original sizes used at training-time. At that point I get an error like this:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,5] vs. shape[1] = [2,7]
     [[Node: import/rnn/while/basic_rnn_cell/basic_rnn_cell_1/concat = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](import/rnn/while/TensorArrayReadV3, import/rnn/while/Identity_2, import/rnn/while/basic_rnn_cell/basic_rnn_cell_1/concat/axis)]]
```

To illustrate and reproduce the problem, please consider the following minimal examples.

- `v1`: a graph is created with arbitrary batch size and sequence length. This works fine but unfortunately I must use a fixed batch size and sequence length at training-time and must use an arbitrary batch size and sequence length at test-time so I can't use this simple approach.
- `v2a`: we simulate creating the training-time graph with fixed batch size (2) and sequence length (3) and freeze the graph.
- `v2ba`: we demonstrate that loading the frozen model in unchanged still produces the same results.
- `v2bb`: we demonstrate that loading the frozen model in with a replaced input that still uses a fixed batch size and sequence length still produces the same results.
- `v2bc`: we demonstrate that loading the frozen model in with a replaced input that uses arbitrary batch size and sequence length still produces the same results, *as long as the input is shaped according to the original batch size and sequence length*. It works with `data` but fails with `data2` -- the only difference being the batch size of the former is 2 and the batch size of the latter is 1.

**Is it possible to change an RNN graph via the `input_map` argument to `tf.import_graph_def` such that the input no longer has a fixed batch size and sequence length?**

The following code works with TensorFlow 1.1 RC2 and may work with TensorFlow 1.0.

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import graph_util as tf_graph_util
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn as tfc_rnn


def v1(data):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        tf.set_random_seed(1)
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 5))
        _, s = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(tfc_rnn.BasicRNNCell(7), x, dtype=tf.float32)

        with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            print session.run(s, feed_dict={x: data})


def v2a():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        tf.set_random_seed(1)
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3, 5), name="x")
        _, s = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(tfc_rnn.BasicRNNCell(7), x, dtype=tf.float32)

        with tf.Session() as session:
            session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            return tf_graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                session, session.graph_def, [s.op.name]), s.name


def v2ba((graph_def, s_name), data):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        x, s = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,
                                   return_elements=["x:0", s_name])

        with tf.Session() as session:
            print '2ba', session.run(s, feed_dict={x: data})


def v2bb((graph_def, s_name), data):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 3, 5))
        [s] = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={"x:0": x},
                                  return_elements=[s_name])

        with tf.Session() as session:
            print '2bb', session.run(s, feed_dict={x: data})


def v2bc((graph_def, s_name), data):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None, 5))
        [s] = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, input_map={"x:0": x},
                                  return_elements=[s_name])

        with tf.Session() as session:
            print '2bc', session.run(s, feed_dict={x: data})


def main():
    data1 = numpy.random.random_sample((2, 3, 5))
    data2 = numpy.random.random_sample((1, 3, 5))
    v1(data1)
    model = v2a()
    v2ba(model, data1)
    v2bb(model, data1)
    v2bc(model, data1)
    v2bc(model, data2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in tensorflow that has been going on for a while: you cannot reliably replace a placeholder with a defined shape with another one with (partially) undefined shape.

You will find a related issue filed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21185), which apparently did not get much attention.